# need to convert string list into integers and replace a number if its divisible by 3

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I'm in school and am struggling with this problem. any insight would be great.

inside a function convert these string-type integers into integer-type.
If the number within the list is divisible by 3, multiply it by 10, then replace it.

For example:
If your my_ints = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], your output should be [1, 2, 30, 4, 5]

Im not sure if im suppose to use my_ints as the list or if im calling them in a function

```
def comp2(*args):
    for i in range(len(args)):
        integer = [int(i) for i in args]
    
        for i in integer:
           if i%3 == 0:
        
       
            print(integer)
        
           
           
            

comp2('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')

output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You don't have any code here that multiplies a number  by 10.  Where were you expecting that to happen?

Comment: i didnt know the next step, i dont know the proper syntax to mutiply the number i need and then how to replace it in the list

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to use nested loop for this.
2. You can do it all with one for loop instead of two:

```
def comp2(*args):
    integers = []
    for i in args:
        if int(i)%3 == 0:
            integers.append(int(i) * 10)
        else:
            integers.append(int(i))
```

You could also use [*list comprehension*](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)  to do it:

```
def comp2(*args):
    integers = [int(i) if int(i) % 3 != 0 else int(i)*10 for i in args ]
    print(integers)
        

comp2('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 30, 4, 5]
```

---

Notes on your code:

** lets call the number of arguments `n`

```py
def comp2(*args):
    for i in range(len(args)): # loops n times
        integer = [int(i) for i in args] # uses list comprehension to create new list in each iteration 
    
        for i in integer: # for each iteration it goes through every element in the list and does what you worte
            print(integer) # if you tried to print how many time this section gets executed you will see that it happens n^2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like your function is supposed to accept **one** argument which is a *list* of integer strings.

So the **call** to your function should look like this:

```
comp2(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
```

Next, inside the function, you should iterate over that list and convert to integers, also multiply by 10 if needed:

```
def comp2(my_ints):
    new_ints = []
    for x in my_ints:
        newx = int(x)
        if newx % 3 == 0:
            new_ints.append(newx * 10)
        else:
            new_ints.append(newx)
    print(new_ints)
```

Comment: thank you so much, im struggling to learn this over online classes, i really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
l =  ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

def f(l):
    return [int(x) * 10 if int(x) % 3 == 0 else int(x) for x in l]
```

f(l)

[1, 2, 30, 4, 5]

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Im not sure if im suppose to use my_ints as the list or if im calling them in a function ..."*

The name used for the parameter is used solely for the *method scope*.
It doesn't need to have a similar name.

Parse each *list* value using the *[map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)* *built-in function*.

Then, iterate *args* with the *[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)* *function*, and increase any value when *mod 3* is *0*.

```py
def comp2(args):
    args = list(map(int, args))
    for i, x in enumerate(args):
        if not x % 3: args[i] *= 10
    return args
```

Additionally, you could use a *[list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*.

```py
args = [x if x % 3 else x * 10 for x in map(int, args)]
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 30, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(argmts):
    Inventory = []
    for x in argmts:
        if int(x) % 3 == 0:
            Inventory.append(int(x)*10)
        else:
            Inventory.append(int(x))
    return(Inventory)

#using the example given in question
print(convert(['1','2','3','4','5']))
```

You can use this code to obtain the desired output.

The output will be
`[1, 2, 30, 4, 5]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).